# Function. Passing by reference

Tags: php, function, pass-by-reference

I have come across the following statement from php manual

> The following things can be passed by reference:
>
> > Variables, i.e. foo($a)
> >
> > New statements, i.e. foo(new foobar())
> >
> > References returned from functions, i.e.

And here's an example that doesn't work:

```
<?php
function foo(&$var)
{
    $var++;
}
function bar()
{
    $a = 5;
    return $a;
}
foo(bar());
```

I am trying to understand why it doesn't work.

bar() returns '5' by value, which foo() references, so why does PHP doesn't permit this behavior?

Is this related to this excerpt from manual:

> No other expressions should be passed by reference, as the result is
>   undefined. For example, the following examples of passing by reference
>   are invalid

However, to me this doesn't make sense because, bar() returns an actual value, not undefined.

Comment: What is that `5` that is returned from bar()? It's simply a value. It isn't a variable that can be passed by reference to foo(). It's a value waiting to be assigned to some variable, and only then will it have a reference.

Comment: Yeah but usually when you pass by reference you want to continue using it (using a variable). P.S: By 5.3+ (or smth) passing by reference is removed (for variables)

Comment: @KA_lin - __call time__ pass by reference is deprecated in 5.3 (and removed in 5.4); __pass by reference__ is still permitted

Comment: `bar()` didn't return a variable, an object nor a reference. It returned a value, like Mark said. Therefore, your example won't work by the very definition you posted initially.

Answer (score 0):

Only variables should be passed by reference, so this will work

```
function foo(&$var)
{
    $var++;
}
function bar()
{
    $a = 5;
    return $a;
}
$a = bar();
foo($a);
var_dump($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong... here is your example a bit more completed.

```
function foo(&$var)
{
    $var++;
    return $var;
}
function bar()
{
    $a = 5;
    return $a;
}
echo foo($a=bar())."\n";
echo $a . "\n";
```

It outputs the expected.
6
5
On PHP 5.6.3

Comment: Can you explain why in the 2nd case, $a = 5? Shouldn't it be also 6 because foo() increases by reference?